# Spectral radius and invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, spectral-radius

How would I show that if the spectral radius of a matrix $M$ is less than $1$ then the matrix $I - M$ is invertible?

I believe that I'm supposed to work towards a contradiction to show that if the matrix was singular then 1 would be an eigenvalue, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: the spectral radius of the zero matrix is less than one.

Comment: It helps to get the question right.  I suspect it should be: if the spectral radius of $M$ is less than $1$, then $I - M$ is invertible.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $I-M$ is not invertible, then its kernel is not trivial so $\exists v\ne 0$ such that 
$$
(I-M)v=0
$$
i.e. $Mv=v$. This shows that 1 is an eigenvalue of $M$ so $1\in \sigma(M)$, thus $\rho(M),$ the spectral radius of $M$, satisfies $\rho(M)\ge 1$.